# fetch and deploy PHP application on AWS elasticbeanstalk through git

Tags: php, git, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a forum application uploaded to AWS elasticbeanstalk by zip package. but now I need to change some code, but now I don't know how should I get access to the code?

Is it possible for me to fetch this code back to local , make change and redeploy with "git push"? just like how Heroku deploy works?

I try to google it but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really two parts to your questions.

1. To get to the code, you have to go to S3. You should see a elastic beanstalk bucket with your zip file in it.
2. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.sdlc.html) is a pretty good guide to get you started with elastic beanstalk command line (including git aws.push).